# How to create a new column in query then populate with a simple calc X*Y

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns. One is MW and the other is Price. I want to create a sql query that creates a third imaginary column called AwardPrice, and within that it will be one column (MW) * another column (Price). These two columns already exist in the same fact table.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a computed column:

```
alter table t add AwardPrice as (MW * Price);
```

This value is calculated when you *query* the table, so the value is always accurate and up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

> How to create a new column in query . . .
>
> I want to create a sql query that creates...

I suppose that you want to do that in a `SELECT` statement as

```
SELECT *, MW * Price As AwardPrice
FROM YourTableNameHere;
```